# How to analysis the output of powertop to increase battery lifetime

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery

I'm new to ubuntu using 12.04LTS .Please help me by steps.Thanks all.

```
anoy@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode
5
```

PowerTOP 1.97     Overview   Idle stats   Frequency stats   Device stats   Tunables

The battery reports a discharge rate of 21.7 W

Summary: 551.2 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/second and 0.0 VFS ops/sec

```
            Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
         43.7 ms/s     229.1        Process        /usr/lib/firefox-trunk/fi
         17.0 ms/s     109.0        Process        /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/
          2.1 ms/s      42.7        Timer          tick_sched_timer
          4.2 ms/s      35.5        Process        metacity
          1.1 ms/s      34.9        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
        184.2 ms/s     16.9        Process        [loop0]
          1.4 ms/s      16.1        Interrupt      [44] i915
          1.5 ms/s       8.4        Interrupt      [16] ehci_hcd:usb1
          2.7 ms/s       6.7        Process        /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --xi
        585.4 ms/s      7.4        Interrupt      [7] sched(softirq)
        289.0 ms/s      6.2        Process        mount.ntfs /dev/disk/by-uuid
          1.4 ms/s       5.5        Process        /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon
          2.0 ms/s       5.2        Process        gnome-terminal
          1.6 ms/s       3.6        Process        unity-2d-shell
          0.8 ms/s       2.9        Process        unity-2d-panel
          7.1 ms/s       0.1        kWork          ieee80211_scan_work
          0.8 ms/s       2.5        Process        //bin/dbus-daemon --fork
         61.4 ms/s      2.5        Process        [ktpacpi_nvramd]
        382.4 ms/s      2.1        Process        /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daem
        193.2 ms/s      2.0        Interrupt      [4] block(softirq)
          2.2 ms/s       0.9        Process        /usr/bin/python /usr/shar
        317.0 ms/s      1.5        Process        /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi
          4.0 ms/s       0.0        Process        [kworker/u:2]
        168.6 ms/s   1.0        Process        /bin/dbus-daemon --config-fi
         42.7 ms/s   0.8        kWork          ieee80211_iface_work
         41.7 ms/s   0.8        Process        /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volum
          5.0 ms/s   0.8        kWork          cfq_kick_queue
        212.1 ms/s   0.7        Interrupt      [9] RCU(softirq)
        313.1 ms/s   0.3        Process        /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-s
          9.6 ms/s   0.4        kWork          i915_gem_retire_work_handler
```

The battery reports a discharge rate of 18.7 W

```
          Usage     Device name
          8.8%        CPU use
         73.3%        Display backlight
         73.3%        Display backlight
         29.8%        Display backlight
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chi
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chi
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chi
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chi
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chi
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chi
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chi
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chi
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chi
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Proc
        100.0%        PCI Device: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE
        100.0%        USB Device: usb-device-04b3-3107
        100.0%        PCI Device: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/81
        100.0%        USB device: EHCI Host Controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Seymo
        100.0%        PCI Device: Ricoh Co Ltd Device e823
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generat
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Proc
        100.0%        Radio device: rtl8192ce
        100.0%        USB Device: usb-device-8087-0024
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chi
         71.1 pkts/s  Network interface: wlan0 (rtl8192ce)
          0.0 pkts/s  Network interface: eth0 (r8169)
          0.0 rpm     Laptop fan
          0.0%        Radio device: thinkpad_acpi
          0.0%        Audio codec hwC0D0: Conexant
          0.0%        Audio codec hwC0D3: Intel
```

Tunables

```
Bad           Enable SATA link power management for /dev/sda<br/>
Bad           NMI watchdog should be turned off<br/>
Bad           VM writeback timeout<br/>
Bad           Autosuspend for unknown USB device 1-1.3 (04b3:3107)<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Int<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 po<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Seymour [Radeon HD 64<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Process<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI<br/>
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB<br/>
Good          Enable Audio codec power management<br/>
Good          Power Aware CPU scheduler<br/>
Good          Autosuspend for USB device EHCI Host Controller [usb1]<br/>
Good          Autosuspend for unknown USB device 2-1 (8087:0024)<br/>
Good          Autosuspend for USB device Integrated Camera (Ricoh Company Ltd.)<br/>
Good          Autosuspend for USB device EHCI Host Controller [usb2]<br/>
Good          Autosuspend for unknown USB device 1-1 (8087:0024)<br/>
Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi<br/>
Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High<br/>
Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Ricoh Co Ltd Device e823<br/>
Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express<br/>
Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRA<br/>
Good          Wake-on-lan status for device eth0<br/>
Good          Wake-on-lan status for device wlan0<br/>
Good          Using 'ondemand' cpufreq governor<br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests on various machines for Precise 12.04 LTS on the Good/Bad powertop settings.  My research results are here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/power-benchmarking/powertop-good-bad-recommendations/results.txt

..and supporting data here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/power-benchmarking/powertop-good-bad-recommendations/powertop-good-bad-recommendations.ods

The best and least risk changes we added to the pm-utils package in Precise to help save power on battery for laptops.

By using a high precision multimeter it was apparent that some "Good" savings recommendations from powertop may in fact not be that useful, so one needs a lot of trial and error and an accurate way of assessing power consumption to ensure you select the optimal configuration for your hardware.

If you want to know more about the work that went into saving power in Precise, please refer to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement